# How can I add FirebaseObjectObservables into a variable of FirebaseListObservable in angularfire2

Tags: typescript, angularfire2

In normal javascript array it is possible to do this

```
let fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.push("Kiwi");
```

How can I achieve something like below, cos this implementation gives me an error. I am working with angularfire2

```
let job1 = this.db.object("/Jobs/job1");
let job2 = this.db.object("/Jobs/job2");


let jobselection: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>; 
 jobselection.push(job1);
 jobselection.push(job2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add FirebaseObjectObservable to a FirebaseListObservable.

A FirebaseListObservable is representing a list in your db. E. g. all jobs in your "/Jobs/" node.

```
let jobs:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>=this.db.list("/Jobs");
```

This will give you a list with all your jobs and you can push new jobs to that list.

```
jobs.push({foo:bar});
```